# Error while getting public data from twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

```
String status;
            IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> twitterStatus = twitterService.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
            foreach(String status in twitterStatus)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(twitterStatus);
            }
```

Why it give can not convert string type error in foreach loop ?
this is my whole code

```
namespace TweetingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TwitterClientInfo twitterClientInfo = new TwitterClientInfo();
            twitterClientInfo.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey; //Read ConsumerKey out of the app.config
            twitterClientInfo.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret; //Read the ConsumerSecret out the app.config

            TwitterService twitterService = new TwitterService(twitterClientInfo);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessToken) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessTokenSecret))
            {
                //Now we need the Token and TokenSecret

                //Firstly we need the RequestToken and the AuthorisationUrl
                OAuthRequestToken requestToken = twitterService.GetRequestToken();
                string authUrl = twitterService.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken).ToString();

                //authUrl is just a URL we can open IE and paste it in if we want
                Console.WriteLine("Please Allow This App to send Tweets on your behalf");
                //Process.Start(authUrl); //Launches a browser that'll go to the AuthUrl.

                //Allow the App
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the PIN from the Browser:");
                string pin = Console.ReadLine();

                OAuthAccessToken accessToken = twitterService.GetAccessToken(requestToken, pin);

                string token = accessToken.Token; //Attach the Debugger and put a break point here
                string tokenSecret = accessToken.TokenSecret; //And another Breakpoint here

                Console.WriteLine("Write Down The AccessToken: " + token);
                Console.WriteLine("Write Down the AccessTokenSecret: " + tokenSecret);
            }

            twitterService.AuthenticateWith(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);

            //Console.WriteLine("Enter a Tweet");
            //string tweetMessage;
            //string data;
            //string ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline;
            //string TwitterUserStreamStatus = ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
            //TwitterStatus=ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
            //tweetMessage = Console.ReadLine();
            //ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline = Console.ReadLine();
            //TwitterStatus twitterStatus = twitterService.SendTweet(tweetMessage);
            //TwitterStatus twitterStatus = twitterService.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
            //String status;
            IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = twitterService.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
           foreach(var tweet in tweets)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(tweet);
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
            }
            //twitterStatus=Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

This is my whole code on which I am working and facing just one error on foreach loop which is my lack of knowledge in C#

Comment: what does the error say? Can you put the Exception text or message

Comment: I update it , kindly check it and I need output , I don't want exception

Comment: You still have not posted the exception details as asked for by the other posters. Also your twitterStatus is an IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>. Is this TwitterStatus class, the same as a string or at least derived from string?

Comment: I did it but it give me error on for loop : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Amitd I upload my whole code

Comment: Have you registered your app on twitter .. this site will show you how http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/13/A-Simple-Twitter-Client-in-C-with-OAUTH-using-TweetSharp.aspx

Comment: yes I reg my application

Comment: ah good then did u replace lines 9 and 10 with the details from twitter..*pls dont post those key and secret *here* ..see step 4 in above link..  u will also need lines 22 - 30 in your code

Comment: yes these lines are in my code but I didn't post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something like this..

```
 using TweetSharp;

    TwitterService service = new TwitterService();
    IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = service.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
    foreach (var tweet in tweets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
    }
```

Also try this code to see why it is failing.. try to debug response.StatusCode

```
using TweetSharp;

TwitterService service = new TwitterService();
IAsyncResult result = service.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline(
    (tweets, response) =>
        {
            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                foreach (var tweet in tweets)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} said '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
                }
            }
        });
```

More here : https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: you need to follow this article.. step by step  guide ..you will need register your app with twiiter.  http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/13/A-Simple-Twitter-Client-in-C-with-OAUTH-using-TweetSharp.aspx

Comment: I am registered , as I already crawl dataset from twitter from python , and now am using c# , am registered

Comment: updated my answer can u check what you get for response.StatusCode ?

Comment: put a break point on the "if" line and check add a watch to response.StatusCode value and tweets list.

Answer (score 0):

The object you are itterating through is of type "TwitterStatus", not string... so you are confusing it when you try to automatically cast a TwitterStatus object as a string.

Your question is very vague, so I'm going to assume your TitterStatus object has a "Text" property for the purposes of this answer.

```
foreach(TwitterStatus status in twitterStatus)
{
   Console.WriteLine(status.Text);
}
```

> (just replace the ".Text" with whatever property of TwitterStatus
>   holds the status text)

Comment: Use the new keyword to create an object instance !!! this is now the error this shows on foreach loop

Comment: Sounds like twitterStatus is null.  is your TwitterService call returning values?

Comment: Thanks! when you break after your service call to ListTweetsOnPublic...(), is the ienumerable list of "tweets" getting filled?

Comment: this is thing which confusing me , thats why I upload my code , I think ienumerable list of tweets is empty

Comment: I'm seeing your code snippet looks like it came from https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp.  The only difference I see here is that he declares his service: TwitterService service = new TwitterService();   (without passing in the client info parameter)

Comment: Also - just checking that your "twitterService" is authenticating ok and that you are registered (good comment from amitd)

Comment: I am registered , as I already crawl dataset from twitter from python , and now am using c# , am registered and I update my statues on twitter from the same code

Comment: Have you been able to verify if the ienumerable list is empty after the ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline() call?  If so, do you get any error info in why it failed?